# Force FFmpeg output only TCP as RTSP proxy

Tags: ffmpeg, tcp, proxy, rtsp

There are lot of topics around about RTSP and FFmpeg, but in none of them I have found how to force FFmpeg outputing a TCP RTSP instead of default UDP.
I know how to force the input to TCP, with `-rtsp_transport tcp` option, but I cannot find how to force the output.
Someone solved suggesting to use avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, &options); but did not say nothing mode about that, and this is too generic info.
Thanks a lot for help!

I am using this string, it connect to first source by TCP, but FFmpeg is not opening a TCP listenng port. It does open 4 UDP ports with different values (far from what I have specified for tcp), anyway I have tried to connect to them too with VLC, but no one works.

```
ffmpeg -re -i rtsp://adminassord@rtsp.source:554/live.sdp -rtsp_transport tcp -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp:/192.168.0.100:50041/
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it using https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server
in the end you may get a TCP stream from the rtsp://serverIP:port/proxied

it seems there are no ways to tell ffmpeg to stream on TCP only